# Do not understand window.TAB reference

Tags: javascript

https://github.com/daveloyall/quickjsonformatter/blob/master/index.html

Want to study above code and there are just too many things I don't understand.

```
function SetTab(){
    var select = $id("TabSize");
    window.TAB = MultiplyString(parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value), window.SINGLE_TAB);
}
```

For an example above, is window.TAB user created Global object?( or user created global window's methods? Just not sure what this is doing)

Comment: Yes in JS (well browser based JS at least), `window` is the global object. So `TAB` becomes a both a global variable and a property of `window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.TAB` is a variable being used to store the tab character repeated as many times as the user selects from `#TabSize`. Storing it on `window` makes it accessible everywhere in the code; a global variable, like you say.

The custom `MultiplyString` function is used to repeat the global SINGLE_TAB variable (which is initialised [on line 10](https://github.com/daveloyall/quickjsonformatter/blob/master/index.html#L10) to be the tab character).

`TAB` is later used on lines [106](https://github.com/daveloyall/quickjsonformatter/blob/master/index.html#L106) and [116](https://github.com/daveloyall/quickjsonformatter/blob/master/index.html#L116) to indent the output.

Comment: Need to study more on your comment but thank you for giving me direction!

Comment: If you’re trying to learn Javascript, this instance doesn’t seem like the most suitable example. It’s not that “idiomatic”, meaning it doesn’t follow the general conventions of Javascript programming.

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for this exact solution and found it on that page and now I want to understand how it works. It does seem very cryptic (as I do understand some javascript )